# i'm installed 2 modules and i get this error if i want command setup:upgrade and compile

Tags: magento2.3.4

i'm installed module and i get this error if i want command setup:upgrade and compile

first problem with setup:upgrade i get this error

```
Column definition "customer_group_id" and reference column definition "customer_group_id" are different in tables "mgz_checkoutsuccesspage_rule_customer_group" and "customer_group"
```

and number 2 error if i make this command setup:di:compile

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mirasvit\Core\Ui\QuickDataBar\SparklineDataBlock' not found in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Mirasvit/RewardsAdminUi/Ui/QuickDataBar/EarnedDataBlock.php on line 25
```

any help please to fix this errors